# don't display variable in result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to optimize this select, because there is in CASE the same select twice and query need twice so long time to run:

```
SELECT sc.ID, 
      (CASE WHEN (SELECT SUM(scu.OK) 
                    FROM `SCU` scu 
                    WHERE scu.ID = _ID
                        AND scu.CCC = sc.ID
                    GROUP BY scu.ISC)
       IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
                    (SELECT SUM(scu.OK) 
                    FROM `SCU` scu 
                        WHERE scu.ID = _ID
                            AND scu.CCC = sc.ID
                        GROUP BY scu.ISC)
      END )as 'STATUS'
FROM    ( SELECT `ID` 
            FROM `STORE`
            WHERE `STATE`=1
            ORDER BY `NUMBERIN` DESC) sc
GROUP BY sc.ID;
```

I tried something like this

```
SELECT sc.ID, 
       @STATUS:=(SELECT SUM(scu.OK) 
                    FROM `SCU` scu 
                    WHERE scu.ID = _ID
                        AND scu.CCC = sc.ID
                    GROUP BY scu.ISC),
      (CASE WHEN @STATUS
       IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @STATUS
       END ) as 'STATUS'
FROM    ( SELECT `ID` 
            FROM `STORE`
            WHERE `STATE`=1
            ORDER BY `NUMBERIN` DESC) sc
GROUP BY sc.ID;
```

but it returns me another column with **@STATUS** variable but it should not. 
Result should have ID and STATUS column. Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is COALESCE - that can be used to replace a NULL with a specific value.

```
SELECT sc.ID, 
      COALESCE((SELECT SUM(scu.OK) 
                    FROM `SCU` scu 
                    WHERE scu.ID = _ID
                        AND scu.CCC = sc.ID
                    GROUP BY scu.ISC),0) as 'STATUS'      
FROM    ( SELECT `ID` 
            FROM `STORE`
            WHERE `STATE`=1
            ORDER BY `NUMBERIN` DESC) sc
GROUP BY sc.ID;
```

---

Comment: even better than IFNULL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like following using `IFNULL`:

```
SELECT sc.ID, 
       IFNULL(@STATUS:=(SELECT SUM(scu.OK) 
                    FROM `SCU` scu 
                    WHERE scu.ID = _ID
                        AND scu.CCC = sc.ID
                    GROUP BY scu.ISC),0,@STATUS) AS `STATUS`
FROM    ( SELECT `ID` 
            FROM `STORE`
            WHERE `STATE`=1
            ORDER BY `NUMBERIN` DESC) sc
GROUP BY sc.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Select 
id, 
      (CASE WHEN status
       IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE status
       END ) as 'STATUS'
from
(SELECT sc.ID, 
       (SELECT SUM(scu.OK) 
                    FROM `SCU` scu 
                    WHERE scu.ID = _ID
                        AND scu.CCC = sc.ID
                    GROUP BY scu.ISC) as status
FROM    ( SELECT `ID` 
            FROM `STORE`
            WHERE `STATE`=1
            ORDER BY `NUMBERIN` DESC) sc
GROUP BY sc.ID) temp
```

Sorry, i typed them in smart phone. 
Hope it helps